# Taking info from closed workbook that has variable name

Tags: vba, excel

I am wondering if there is a way to not have to open a workbook to get the information from it. The issue is I am having the user select the file first because the name changes. So I am using Application.GetOpenFilename. Once they select it, since it doesn't actually open, I am trying to just grab some cells from there and copy them over. I have some other cells using vlookups referencing a workbook in the same way but this seems different or won't work. Here is the code:

```
Dim Window3 As String
Dim x As String
Dim lNewBracketLocation As Long
Dim shtName As String


' Prompt
strPrompt = "Please select the last 'HC Report' located in" & vbCrLf & _
    "'C:\file\file\'" & vbCrLf & _
    "before the dates of this Report." & vbCrLf & _
    "This will be used to find the Interns that are currently working." & vbCrLf & _
    "For example, if the date of this report is 9-8-17, you would want to use the 'August 2017.xlsx.' report."

' Dialog's Title
strTitle = "Latest Report"

'Display MessageBox
iRet = MsgBox(strPrompt, vbOK, strTitle)

Window3 = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", _
    Title:="Choose previous quarter's file", MultiSelect:=False)

MsgBox "You selected " & Window3

'below is some extra code from where I used this same startegy for VLOOKUP. 
'Not sure if this "x" variable will be needed.

lNewBracketLocation = InStrRev(Window2, Application.PathSeparator)
'Edit the string to suit the VLOOKUP formula - insert "["
x = Left$(Window2, lNewBracketLocation) & "[" & Right$(Window2, Len(Window2) - lNewBracketLocation)

Dim wb3 As Workbook

'I want to do all of this WITHOUT opening this next file. Is that possible?
' If I open this file it works. but I am trying to do it without opening. 
'Because it takes a minute
'Set wb3 = Workbooks.Open(Window3)


shtName = wb3.Worksheets("Team Members").name
'*******RIGHT here IS WHERE IT ERRORS******************
'Run-time error '91':
'Object variable or With block variable not set



Stop


wb3.Sheets(shtName).Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$2769").autofilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Interns"
Range("A2768").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.COPY
```

This is some other code I have that takes the vlookup without actually opening the other file. Can I do kind of the same thing? I can't get it to work.

```
Dim Window2 As String
Dim x As String
Dim lNewBracketLocation As Long

Window2 = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", _
    Title:="Choose previous quarter's file", MultiSelect:=False)

MsgBox "You selected " & Window2
'Find the last instance in the string of the path separator "\"
lNewBracketLocation = InStrRev(Window2, Application.PathSeparator)
'Edit the string to suit the VLOOKUP formula - insert "["
x = Left$(Window2, lNewBracketLocation) & "[" & Right$(Window2, Len(Window2) - lNewBracketLocation)

shtName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).name


Stop


MainWindow.Activate
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("AI2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC2,'" & x & "]shtName'!R3C2:R9694C49, 23, FALSE)"
Range("AJ2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC2,'" & x & "]shtName'!R3C2:R9694C49, 19, FALSE)"
Range("AK2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC2,'" & x & "]shtName'!R3C2:R9694C49, 20, FALSE)"
Range("AL2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC36,'" & x & "]shtName'!R3C2:R9694C49, 23, FALSE)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *impossible* to copy cells across from a closed workbook. The vlookups are a different story as Excel caches a copy of the result to display when the external workbook is closed.

Just like what you're trying to do, i.e., you need to have the external file opened once to grab the data. With vlookup it's when the formula is typed/pasted into the sheet. At that time the external workbook must either be open or Excel opens it behind the scenes when you select the file from the `Update Values:Book1.xlsm` file selection dialog. With your code, it's when you want to grab the data. You ***must*** open it for you to cache the data *yourself*.

However you can solve the time issue by using this:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Set wb3 = Workbooks.Open(Window3)
```

and then after you close the workbook, this:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: I use the Application.GetFilename code and then use a vlookup to get info from that file in another part of my file and that does not open but it gets the info. So I figured I could do it with this one.

I think I need to try using that code again and start over. I have changed too many things. 

Can I not just set a variable to the file path and then reference that or something?

I will post the code I use for the vlookup in the main post

Comment: @Robillard It doesn't actually get the data from the closed file. Excel caches a copy of the result when the file was last opened. If the external file has changed you won't see the update unless you open it.

Comment: I only need to take the info once. I then copy paste special the values in because I don't want the vlookup there. I do it once then send the report. Then will do it again with a different file next time. So does the application.getfilename actually open the file? I am just confused because that one works but I can't get mine to work. I feel like I should be able to just reference it like I do in the vlookup.

Comment: @Robillard No. All the getfilename does is, well, *get the file name*. It's designed to allow the user to choose a file to open. You still have to manually open it yourself though. See my previous comment and the updated answer for explanation re vlookup.

Comment: So if I have NEVER opened the file before, will the VLOOKUP still work? For my VLOOKUP code I have opened that file before, but that code doesn't specifically open it. Would it work if I have NEVER opened it before?

Comment: @Robillard Read my updated answer - If I recall correctly you can't create a vlookup to a closed file without getting an error. Will check.

Comment: I just used my same code for the VLOOKUP and selected a file I have never opened before. It still worked : /

Comment: @Robillard That's because Excel **opened** the file behind the scenes to get the data to cache. It only happens *when you type a formula in a worksheet*. You can't do the same in VBA.

Comment: hmm alright. Thank you. I will try your idea to lessen the time. I gotta re work the code so it works again because I deleted some and started over. Probably should have kept that part that worked when I opened the file...